# Integer overflow issues

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> getRow(int rowIndex) {
vector<int> result;
if(rowIndex < 0)   return result;
if(rowIndex == 0){
    result.push_back(1);
    return result;
}
for(int i = 0; i < rowIndex+1; i++){
    if(i == 0)  result.push_back(1);
    else{
        result.push_back(result[i-1] * (rowIndex+1-i)/i);
    }
}
return result;
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> tmp = getRow(30);
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++){
        cout << tmp[i] << " ";   
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Pascal's triangle - coding problem from LeetCode, which asks to output the nth row of the Pascal triangle. With `rowIndex=30`, the output looks like:

```
1 30 435 4060 27405 142506 593775 2035800 5852925 14307150 30045015 54627300 86493225 119759850 145422675 -131213633 -123012780 -101304642 -73164463 -46209134 -25415023 -12102391 -4950978 -1722079 -502273 -120545 -23181 -3434 -367 -25 0
```

Obviously, there is an overflow problem. Now to fix this, I modified the line `result.push_back(result[i-1] * (rowIndex+1-i)/i);` to `result.push_back((double)result[i-1] * (double)(rowIndex+1-i)/i);`. And it produces the correct output:

```
1 30 435 4060 27405 142506 593775 2035800 5852925 14307150 30045015 54627300 86493225 119759850 145422675 155117520 145422675 119759850 86493225 54627300 30045015 14307150 5852925 2035800 593775 142506 27405 4060 435 30 1
```

Can someone explain what exactly is the problem here?
We know that the range of signed integer value is -2147483648 to 2147483647. Without casting, why at value `155117520` is printed as overflow `-131213633`?

Comment: Did you actually want a `double` expression from this statement in 1st place before _casting to `int`_: `result[i-1] * (rowIndex+1-i)/i`?

Comment: Well, what is 145422675 * (rowIndex+1-i) ?

Comment: `result[i-1] * (rowIndex+1-i)` results in an int overflow. So you already have a problem when it gets to the `\i` part. Casting to double avoids the `result[i-1] * (rowIndex+1-i)` int overflow, and so the `\i` bit works as expected.

Comment: Try adding parentheses so that the division is done first?

Comment: @celticminstrel ... good call ... (2*3)/4 is the same as 2*(3/4) after all.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now.

Comment: Without casting, I don't think performing division first will help. Take (2*3)/4 as an example, 2*(3/4) = 0, which is incorrect.

Comment: `(2*3)/4=2*(3/4)=6/4` ... only the largest number the division first method works with is `2*(3/4)`, rather than `(2*3)`. Casting is the way to go for a more robust solution though ... why put yourself at the mercy of possible overflows when you can avoid them?!

Comment: I apologize if I missed anything, but `2*(3/4)` is zero. Integer division 3/4 = 0, then 2*0 = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I the expression

```
result[i-1] * (rowIndex+1-i)/i
```

multiplication takes place first, and results in overflow:

```
result[i-1] * (rowIndex + 1-i)
```

and then the result gets divided by `i`, producing the negative output.

---

BTW, if you decide to cast, avoid casting to `double` due to possible rounding issues. You could try `long` instead, but it is perhaps better to use at the first place

```
vector<long>
```

or even

```
vector<unsigned long>
```

or, thanks to **@WorldSEnder**,

```
vector<unsigned long long>
```

Still, be aware that the standard does not guarantee that `long` or `long long` is longer than `int`. Neither it guarantees that `int` is in the range `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`.

Comment: Could you add the suggestion to try `long long int`, too please?